# Is it possible to convert a binary class svm to multiclass svm

Tags: matlab, svm

Is it possible to convert a binary class svm to multiclass svm? As I have to convert the binary class svm to multi class is it possible to do so. If yes please some one can say how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: **no**.

A binary SVM puts one hyperplane between the two classes to separate them. A multiclass SVM puts *multiple* hyperplanes to separate the 3 or more different classes. As you only have *one* hyperplane and no other information, this is not possible.

Though there are cases in which it would be possible to keep the trained binary SVM and extend it:

Assume your binary SVM decides between class `A` and `B`. You now want to know more about `B` and separate all `B`'s into `B1` or `B2`. Then you can use the binary SVM to classify between `A` and `B`, and in a second step, train a new binary SVM to decide between `B1` and `B2`.

Another possibility: Assume your data only contained class `A` and `B` so far. From now on, also a *new* class `C` can occur. You can then use a One-vs-One multiclass SVM strategy (i.e. build binary SVMs to decide between: `A-B`, `A-C`, `B-C`). In that case you can re-use the binary SVM and only train the `A-C` and `B-C` SVMs.

Comment: Thanks for your detail description, as i have to classify 6 classes so i need to use only multiclass svm i guess??

Answer (score 1):

The most common SVM-multiclass classification method build severals SVM for each class VS the rest. In the end the class with the highest score is chosen.

LIBSVM may be useful for you. It is easy to use in matlab.

http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/

Comment: i am encountering installation problem with libsvm with compiler even though visualstudio 12 has already installed.